# LWC lightning-file-upload CSS styling issue

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, css

I would like to use the lightning-file-upload LWC component. But, there is a label on the component which I do not want to use and which seems to mess up the layout. Here is a screenshot where the component is misaligned. This screenshot uses the standard label.

[image: lightning-file-upload WITH label]

Here is a screenshot where the label is empty

[image: lightning-file-upload WITHOUT label]

Here is inspecting the component. The label  can be clearly seen.

[image: Inspection of component WITH label span]

Here is inspecting the component after REMOVING the labels span node. As can be seen the component now aligns as expected!

[image]

How do I go about either completely removing the label  node or updating the CSS styling so that it doesn't create problems?

Comment: Try to give padding bottom to lightning upload button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. SLDS file upload is designed to always have a label, and LWC doesn't allow manipulation of elements inside a component via CSS or direct DOM manipulation. It would be better to add a label to the dropdown, instead. It's the dropdown that's in violation of SLDS guidelines, not the file selector.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox. I was not thinking about this correctly as you say. I added a label to the drop down which solved the alignment issue.